# I'm having trouble with looping in JAVA

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Lab101{
        public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  

     System.out.println("Enter Class Limit:");
     int x = sc.nextInt();

     for (char i=1; i<=x; i++) {
       System.out.println("Enter Student Name: ");
       sc.next().charAt(0);
     }

     System.out.println("Class Is Full");}}

Enter Class Limit:
3
Enter Student Name: 
Input
Enter Student Name: 
Name
Enter Student Name: 
Here
Class Is Full
```

I have solved my problem now. But then I found a new problem!

```
Enter Class Limit:
3
Enter Student Name: 
Input Name
Enter Student Name: 
Enter Student Name: 
Here
Class Is Full
```

once I entered a space. it is counted as two input in one line and skips the second line of entering and proceeding to the third. How do I make it accept space in one line and count it as one so that I can make it like this...

```
Enter Class Limit:
3
Enter Student Name: 
Input Name Here
Enter Student Name: 
Input Name Here
Enter Student Name: 
Input Name Here
Class Is Full
```

Comment: Use `sc.nextLine().charAt(0)`. Also, look at this when you use `nextLine()` you will encounter the same issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods

Comment: Unrelated, but is there a reason why you use a `char` as the iterator on the loop?

Comment: I use char to read the names I input.

Comment: @JosephLota To iterate in a loop you don't need `char`, just with `int` you can do it.

Comment: I've change it. and yeah it works. my problem is solved now

i used sc.nextLine().charAt(0) to accept the spaces and added a blank sc.nextLine() after the sc.nextInt() to fill the skipping of line

Answer (score 2):

You aren't storing (or later displaying) the input. I think you wanted to do both. Also, if you read an `int` with `nextInt()` you must then consume the `nextLine()`. And you could use [`Arrays.toString(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object[]%29) to display your **student names** (so `String`s). Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter Class Limit:");
    int x = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine(); // <-- there's a newline.
    String[] students = new String[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        System.out.printf("Enter Student Name %d: ", i + 1);
        System.out.flush();
        students[i] = sc.nextLine().trim();
    }

    System.out.println("Class Is Full");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(students));
}
```

Comment: Nope i don't need to display the names after. but thanks. I might need this some time.